# python-How to change all values in a column from integers to strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have 10,000 rows in my dataset,With the last column containg 10 unique strings(i.e each string is repeated 1000 times).How can I convert these 10 strings to integers so that I can use them in neural network.

Comment: Can you add some more information to your question like what you've already tried? If you're sure the String can be converted to an int something as simple as `int("1")` should work, but without more context it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are using pandas. For example, you have useful columns list as the following,

```
modelFeatures = [contains all the columns' names you use]
df = df[modelFeatures].astype(str)
print(df)
```

By using `astype` , you can convert any dataframe into int, float or str.